# Is there an easy way to hide/show Console.WriteLines during runtime?

Tags: c#

**Question**: Is there an easy way to hide/show Console.WriteLines made in a project upon running the project?

These Console.WriteLines are used to give me info while debugging, but they should be hidden when my teacher is running the code.

I've tried to make a new project library (.NET framework 4.7.2) which other projects can reference to:

```
//=========================== SCOPE ===========================
//   Help the programmer to show/hide Console.WriteLines
//=============================================================

// TODO: Add verbose-levels

using System;

namespace Information
{
    public static class Verbose
    {
        public static bool On { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And how it would look while being inside another project:

```
using Information;

...

if (Verbose.On) { Console.WriteLine("Text here!"); }
```

Comment: Use `Debug.WriteLine` instead?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thats how the `Debug` static class works, they are conditional methods that only get compiled in to the code when the DEBUG symbol is defined.

Comment: Problem is when my teacher is running the source code he will probably also run it in debug mode. So I was wondering if there's an easy call you can make to make it show or not?

Comment: Just curious why you don't use the debugger for debugging?

Comment: Use the #if with your own Custom Directive instead of DEBUG. You can define your own using `#define MYDIRECTIVE`

Comment: Caius Jard, I never used a debugger before so I always put in a lot of Console.WriteLines. We will learn about debuggers in a couple of weeks. But using a debugger would be much easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should use the System.Diagnostic settings for this purpose.

You can add below configuration section and add console listener.

```
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="primes" switchValue="All">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Then use Trace.WriteLines to redirect trace output to console.

Please note that switchValue attribute controls which statements should be logged to console.   If its value is set to **Off** nothing will be logged on console.

In C# code, you can instantiate like below:

```
TraceSource _source = new TraceSource();
```

Then while writing the log statements you can set the trace level as below:

```
_source.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "statement to be logged");
```

You can understand more [about log levels at this MSDN page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing)

Please [find examples at this MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener?view=netframework-4.7.2) page.

Comment: Thanks for input. Tested it and it works well! But Is there an easy way to hide the Trace.WriteLines?

Comment: What do you mean by hiding lines ? In source code ? or the output of those lines ?

Comment: In the output of those lines, sorry. 

My professor will run the source code in debug mode and dont want to see any console.writelines in its output

Comment: You can set the Trace Level value in the configuration to OFF, updated my anwer for this.

Comment: Manoj thank you so much this works extremely well! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have plenty of choices here:

- Quick way: I assume you are doing a quick and simple homework, I would simply use [`Debug.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2) as suggested by Damien_The_Unbeliever. The output will be in the Output window during Debug only. Alternatively, you can use [#if directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if).
- Proper Tracing using [Trace and Trace Listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener?view=netframework-4.7.2).
- Overkill way: use a logging framework like [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/) or [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/).